# MongoError: Cannot call abortTransaction twice; MongoError: Cannot call abortTransaction after calling commitTransaction

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

When I run the `send` route I have error:
`MongoError: Cannot call abortTransaction twice`
and
`MongoError: Cannot call abortTransaction after calling commitTransaction`.

I have two collections `car` and `color`. And in the same time I want to add to arrays:
`car.colors.push(model); color.brands.push(year);` and save in database. But I want use `withTransaction` and `session` from mongoose. I don't want the situation that due to error, `car.colors.push(model);` will be saved in database, but `color.brands.push(year);` won't be saved.

```
module.exports.send = async (req, res) => {

    const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
  

    if(role === 'car') {
        try {

            await sess.withTransaction(async () => {
                const car = await Cars.findOne({ _id: sender});
                const color = await Colors.findOne({_id: keeper});
    

                let model =  {
                    contentInfo : {
                        msg : msg
                    }
                };

                let year =  {
                    contentInfo : {
                        msg : msg
                    }
                }
        
        
                car.colors.push(model);
                color.brands.push(year);
                
                await car.save({session: sess});
                await color.save({session: sess});
        
                await sess.commitTransaction();

                sess.endSession();

                return res.json(car);
            });

        } catch (error) {
       
            await sess.abortTransaction();
            sess.endSession();

            throw error; 
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you log the `error` before aborting the transaction? What does it say?

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to endSession from within a method call of that session instance.

Comment: @AlexBlex Before I have error: `Error: color validation failed: brands.0: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[{"contentInfo":.....   at path "brands.0"......... _message: 'Color validation failed'`